# append text string from file to a command

Tags: linux, terminal, dpkg, fromfile

How to put a text string from file to the end of a command?

What I want to is to use `sudo dpkg -i` with `|` or `<` or `>` (or whatever else) to input the strin from `file` in which would be the package names. To demonstrate it:

```
$ ls
file  pkg1.deb  pkg2.deb  pkg3.deb  pkg4.deb

$ more file
pkg1.deb pkg3.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i < file
```

and the installation of the selected packages should run.

Info: I am using Ubuntu 13.10 i386

Comment: `file` is any text file … in the example obove it is one that contains two files:

`    $ more file
    pkg1.deb pkg3.deb`

these files are installed it you use the command that @user3392484 suggested:

`    $ sudo dpkg -i $(<file)`

note that you may have a text file named differently—you need to change the `file` accordingly … and also you need to have that `file` and all the deb files that you want to install (e.g., `pkg1.deb pkg3.deb`) in the same directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sudo dpkg -i $(<file)
```

ought to work, assuming that dpkg -i can take multiple package names (don't have a debian box around to check). If not:

```
for X in $(<file) ; do sudo dpkg -i "$X" ; done
```

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i $(<file)` works perfectly :) … thank U :)